# Jenkins integration with selenium, maven, testng, allure reports

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, testng, allure

I will start by saying that im new to using jenkins.

I was trying to integrate selenium project with jenkins, using Maven plugin in jenkins. I was successful in running the test and saving allure results in allure-results folder, just by giving the path to my pom.xml file.

But i also want to generate and publish allure report, so i added allure plugin to jenkins, and gave the path to my allure-results folder. But it was throwing an error:

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.exception.AllurePluginException: Can not generate Allure Report, exit code: 255
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:314)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:231)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Allure Report' marked build as failure
```

After that i tried to make a .bat file in my project directory, and run it using jenkins 'execute windows batch command' plugin, but it throws error, as allure is not identified as a command by it.
Edit: The command i used for this was `allure generate allure-results`.

Then i added code to generate allure report by executing the batch file in my selenium framework itself, so after the test finishes, it just executes a batch file to generate the report, but for some reason that works in the IDE only, and not when running through jenkins.

So, is there any way i can generate allure-report using jenkins, and then publish it?

Comment: can you share the command you used to configure allure report?

Comment: for generating a publishable report, i use 'allure generate' command.

Comment: See if the solution mentioned here works for you: - https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/issues/199

Answer (score 0):

Go to jenkins:/configureTools/, section `Allure Commandline`. This way Jenkins instance will install allure command which you can use to generate reports.